# Conditional expectation $E[X|Y<y]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$ and univariate pdfs $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

Is it true that $E[X|Y < y]$ equals:

$$ \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^y x \frac{f_{XY}(x,y)} {f_{Y}(y)} dydx $$

since $f_{XY}(x | y) = \frac{f_{XY}(x,y)} {f_{Y}(y)} $.

Comment: You need to be a little careful with notation. Does $f_Y^{-1}(y)$ mean the inverse function of $f_Y$ or $\frac{1}{f_Y(y)}$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Good point, clarification added.

Comment: I guess the $dydx$ at the end should be $dxdy$ or that the upper limit of the inner integral is $x$ or that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E[X\mid Y\lt y]=\frac1{F_Y(y)}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\int_{-\infty}^yf_{X,Y}(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm dx.$$